# Return sum value based on 3 category in one column

Tags: powerbi

I have the following simplified dataset:
[Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyHHk.jpg)
As the picture shows, I want to return the values based on the category.

The Cc type 2 cells don't have direct volume, but in the calculation I need to return the following values for them:

1. The yellow highlighted dataset has volume, this should be returned in the final column.
2. The green highlighted cells should return Sub category Z's volume.
3. The blue highlighted cells should return the total volume.

So far I could only return either the total volume or the direct volume.